# What is the regex expression to return the first sequence with only capital letters? See below for some examples

Tags: regex

Examples of what I want to return:

`S:\Help\Help\TRN LN` --> I want to return `TRN LN`

`S:\Help\Help\BBBY\Test` --> I want to return `BBBY`

`S:\Help\Help\IBM\Test\OLD` --> I want to return `IBM`

I have tried the following and it works where I have one word with all caps, but it doesn't work for the first example above where I want to return TRN LN. How can I modify this to get to TRN LN?

I tried:

```
[A-Z]+[A-Z]+?[A-Z]\b
```

Comment: Is slash always the delimiter between sequences?

Comment: Use lookarounds to match a sequence of capital letters or space, preceded by slash or the beginning of the string, and followed by slash or the end of the string.

Comment: yes backslash (i mistakenly put forward slashes above). but in the 1st example i gave above, the phrase i want might not be bracketed by backslashes. there will always be 1 backslash before the phrase though.

Comment: There's an "edit" link below the question, mistakes like that can be fixed.

Comment: If it's not always bracketed by backslashes, what defines the end of the phrase?

Comment: no more characters defines the end of the phrase if there is no backslash

Comment: So like I said above: use a lookahead for backslash or the end of the string `$`

Comment: And a lookbehind for backslash.

Comment: Tutorial on regex lookarounds: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I have tried the following and it works where I have one word with all caps, but it doesn't work for the first example above where I want to return TRN LN. How can I modify this to get to TRN LN?

[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+?[A-Z]\b

Comment: You need spaces: `[A-Z\s]+`. Why do you have `a-z` in one of your groups, since you don't want to match lowercase letters?

Comment: How about just `\b[A-Z\s]+\b` if you don't want to check specifically for backslash?

Comment: that was a typo. got it thanks

Comment: because that would return the "S" in the examples above.

Comment: Right, so you need to use the backslash lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

If `here will always be 1 backslash before the phrase` then you could first match at least a single backslash using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

After matching the backslash, you could capture the first occurrence of matching 2 or more uppercase chars A-Z in a capturing group.

```
^[^\\\r\n]*\\.*?\b([A-Z]{2,}(?: [A-Z]{2,})*)\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\\\r\n]*\\` Match 0+ times not a backslash or a newline, then match `\`
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `\b([A-Z]{2,}(?: [A-Z]{2,})*)` Capture 2 or more uppercase chars between word boundaries in **group 1** with an optional repetition of a space and 2 uppercase chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXG5m3/1)

Answer (score 0):

*ANY* Caps words not bordered by lower case is this :

`(?<![a-z])[A-Z]+(?:\s?[A-Z])*(?![a-z])`

Or, for minimum 2 or more caps would be this :

`(?<![a-z])[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s?[A-Z])*(?![a-z])`

https://regex101.com/r/Lcppi8/2

**___________________________**

Just *FIRST* Caps words versions is this :

`^.*?(?<![a-z])([A-Z]+(?:\s?[A-Z])*)(?![a-z])`

Or, for minimum 2 or more caps would be this :

`^.*?(?<![a-z])([A-Z]{2,}(?:\s?[A-Z])*)(?![a-z])`

https://regex101.com/r/oVTYk1/1

and the word is in capture group 1.